# I want to expose a mysql service through zato - how to accomplish?

Tags: mysql

I'm setting up [Zato](https://zato.io) to use as an ESB for our web application. I'm still getting a feel for how an ESB works, as well as how to set things up.

I'm stuck on getting a mysql server exposed through the ESB. Can someone please get me started?

I have the outgoing connection configured already. How do I expose that connection to the rest of my application?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Once you have a connection to an SQL database, you refer to it in Zato services through 'self.outgoing.sql', like in the example below which is copied over from [SQL usage examples](https://zato.io/docs/progguide/examples/sql.html) from [Zato documentation](https://zato.io/docs/index.html).

In this particular case, all the rows are simply printed out to server log, but you could as well assign them to self.response.payload, for instance, using SimpleIO.

There are other usage examples in documentation too. Unfortunately, I apparently don't have enough reputation on ServerFault to author an answer with more than 2 links.

```
# stdlib
from contextlib import closing

# Zato
from zato.server.service import Service

class MyService(Service):
    def handle(self):

        # Always use templates and bind variables
        template = 'SELECT name FROM http_soap WHERE data_format=:data_format'
        parameters = {'data_format':'json'}

        with closing(self.outgoing.sql.get('my-conn').session()) as session:
            result = session.execute(template, parameters)
            for item in result:
                self.logger.info(item)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Maybe I misunderstand how Zato works, but can I not just expose the whole service as a pass-through rather than putting queries into zato?

Comment: Can you explain in more details what you mean by exposing it as a pass-through one? How would it work? I don't fully understand where queries would go then if not into services?

Comment: I think I have a misunderstanding as to how zato work. I had thought queries would live in the application and the requests would get queued through zato.